# How can I bring a window to the front?

Tags: windows, desktop

I switch windows from using the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, but the application I switch to sometimes stays behind the current window (say [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)). However, in the taskbar, the selected application is [Outlook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook).

Is there a way to force it to (say with a Windows shortcut) to bring the window up front?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Windows does that. Only workaround [apart from a different OS] is to click the window you want :/

Comment: It should come to the front as soon as it gets switched to, unless something else is messing with/preventing it.  Does this always happen or just intermittently?  If you use Alt+Tab instead, does it work as expected?  If you reboot, does it start behaving as it should again?  Which version of Windows?  Which version of Outlook?  Are Windows and Outlook fully up-to-date with their updates?  Are all your drivers on the latest available version?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - anything since Win 7 will do that. They just never fixed it. You can clean as ever you like, it still does it - modal dialogs behind the window they're a modal for is the worst... :(

Comment: @Tetsujin While it happens occasionally in Windows, it's certainly not something that should be happening frequently.  Based on info given here, "Chrome" and "Outlook" aren't going to be modal windows. Perhaps this is just a case of not enough info provided by OP....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if the window is appearing off-screen:

1. Hover over the application on the toolbar
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (if the previous command is overwritten)
3. Click on *Maximize* or *Move*

*[Hyper opens off screen, cannot move it back to the screen (Windows 10) #1682](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1682)*